# 0 in count field for number of rows to display per page in a table view

Tags: forms, gui-design, user-expectation, user-research, data-tables

I have a count field in my page whose screenshot is attached.
When I enter 0 it lists all the records and doesn't show the 0 in the count field.
What is the standard way or user satisfactory way to handle this.
I am a tester and I want to make sure that the end user has the best user experience.

Before entering 0:

[image]

After entering 0:

[image]

Comment: Is the count field supposed to show the total # of records, or is it a control to limit the number of rows per page?

Comment: You're not asking about this, but "count" is a pretty ambiguous word here. I don't know what it means. Is it the number of records shown?

Answer (score 3):

Entering '0' to show all records sounds like the opposite of what the user would expect.

Instead, including a ***Show All Records*** button alongside the *Count* field would better meet the users expectations, and would be **more discoverable**.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a classic developer shortcut of the functionality. Unfortunately, this may not intuitive for an average user. This will depend on who is your persona.

I remember **uTorrent** had a bandwidth allocation setting when you mentioned 0, it basically meant unlimited bandwidth for that particular setting. I do not know if that still holds true.

I can think of a combination of

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMD3aq.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Good anwer - did you forget to "enable" (white background) the box on the right?

Answer (score 0):

### Use a fixed series of ranges to display rows per page so users never have 0 results by errors of omission (or commission).

Since I don't know the context of use, I don't know all the constraints. But preventing user error is always a priority.

- Using ranges from a fixed dropdown will ensure there's never 0 results *except when the database has no records to return; that is not user error, but the state of the system.*
- Allow a 'view all' option. Paging through results is more work for the user.
- If you need to input a specific number (I don't know why a user would) then you conceivable allow a 'custom' range. But again that puts the burden on the user to either remember and associate the results of their actions and may not reflect the system, which could have dozens of records to display.
- Consider redundancy when displaying large rows in a data grid. If you do a row display control, consider the top (and maybe repeat bottom), so this is visible. Test first to see best positioning for your users.
- Indicate the number of results, and how many i'm viewing currently.
- Consider indicating total pages if possible (not shown below). Currently I don't know the number of pages left to explore, it could be 100's. A fixed range results display allows me to get a quick assessment of how many general records I'd want to scope to.
- **Use standard language:** 'count' can imply search result numbers (what the system can return), which are separate from view controls (user controlled).

**User error with items per page is impossible with a fixed range control vs. a numerical input.**

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVAEyB.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>